# SQL query which should not return the null columns

Tags: sql

When I run a SQL query it gives the column which are null but I need columns only if there is a value or else I don't want that column showing in the result area.

Comment: Do you know about the IS NOT NULL clause?   https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

Comment: A SQL query returns a fixed set of columns.  If you want to filter "columns" from the result set, you either need dynamic SQL or to handle this in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter that records by using `WHERE` clause;

```
SELECT * FROM <yourTable> WHERE <theFieldYouWantToSeeWithValue> IS NOT NULL
```